# How can I change my LOD measure aggregation to reflect my exclusion filter?

Tags: tableau-api

I have a LOD Calculated Field I've named 'Total MO' designed to sum all of the values of MeasureOne in the table below.

It looks like this...

```
{FIXED: SUM([MeasureOne])}
```

The table it's plugged into looks like this...

```
╔══════════════╤═════════════════════════╤═════════════════════════╤═══════════════════════════════════╗
║              │ DimensionTwo            │ DimensionTwo            │ Grand Total                       ║
╠══════════════╪════════════╤════════════╪════════════╤════════════╪════════════╤════════════╤═════════╣
║ DimensionOne │ MeasureOne │ MeasureTwo │ MeasureOne │ MeasureTwo │ MeasureOne │ MeasureTwo │ TotalMO ║
╟──────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼─────────╢
║ X            │            │            │ 8          │ 4          │ 8          │ 4          │ 18      ║
╟──────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼─────────╢
║ Y            │ 6          │ 2          │            │            │ 6          │ 2          │ 18      ║
╟──────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼─────────╢
║ Z            │            │            │ 4          │ 6          │ 4          │ 6          │ 18      ║
╟──────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼─────────╢
║ Grand Total  │ 6          │ 2          │ 12         │ 10         │ 18         │ 12         │ 18      ║
╚══════════════╧════════════╧════════════╧════════════╧════════════╧════════════╧════════════╧═════════╝
```

I then built an exclusion filter, which populates as a dimension to remove DimensionOne values if MeasureOne is less than 5. I've called it "Exclude'.
Note: To me that's a Greater Than sign but for whatever reason it works this way (might have to flip 'Exclude', 'Include' - please let me know if I do).

```
IIF([MeasureOne]>5, 'Exclude', 'Include')
```

When I do this my table looks like this...

```
╔══════════════╤═════════════════════════╤═════════════════════════╤═══════════════════════════════════╗
║              │ DimensionTwo            │ DimensionTwo            │ Grand Total                       ║
╠══════════════╪════════════╤════════════╪════════════╤════════════╪════════════╤════════════╤═════════╣
║ DimensionOne │ MeasureOne │ MeasureTwo │ MeasureOne │ MeasureTwo │ MeasureOne │ MeasureTwo │ TotalMO ║
╟──────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼─────────╢
║ X            │            │            │ 8          │ 4          │ 8          │ 4          │ 18      ║
╟──────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼─────────╢
║ Y            │ 6          │ 2          │            │            │ 6          │ 2          │ 18      ║
╟──────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼─────────╢
║ Grand Total  │ 6          │ 2          │ 8          │ 4          │ 14         │ 6          │ 18      ║
╚══════════════╧════════════╧════════════╧════════════╧════════════╧════════════╧════════════╧═════════╝
```

How do I keep the filter (or filter another way) and have the LOD Calculated Field 'TotalMO' reflect the new total of MeasureOne so it looks like this?...

```
╔══════════════╤═════════════════════════╤═════════════════════════╤═══════════════════════════════════╗
║              │ DimensionTwo            │ DimensionTwo            │ Grand Total                       ║
╠══════════════╪════════════╤════════════╪════════════╤════════════╪════════════╤════════════╤═════════╣
║ DimensionOne │ MeasureOne │ MeasureTwo │ MeasureOne │ MeasureTwo │ MeasureOne │ MeasureTwo │ TotalMO ║
╟──────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼─────────╢
║ X            │            │            │ 8          │ 4          │ 8          │ 4          │ 14      ║
╟──────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼─────────╢
║ Y            │ 6          │ 2          │            │            │ 6          │ 2          │ 14      ║
╟──────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼─────────╢
║ Grand Total  │ 6          │ 2          │ 8          │ 4          │ 14         │ 6          │ 14      ║
╚══════════════╧════════════╧════════════╧════════════╧════════════╧════════════╧════════════╧═════════╝
```

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your exclusion filter to Context so LODs are reflected.